# migrating linq sum query to .net core 3.1

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, asp.net-core-3.0

I am migrating from .net core 2.2 to 3.0  and getting error for linq query

```
        var accountList = someOtherList.Select(x => x.AccountNo).ToList();
        var collectedAmount = await _dbContext.AllocPayments
                .Where(p => accountList.Contains(p.AccountNo))
                .SumAsync(x => x.Amount);
```

This is giving error:

> System.InvalidOperationException : The LINQ expression
>   'DbSet
>           .Where(a => __accountList_0.Contains(a.AccountNo))
>           .Sum(a => a.Amount)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client
>   evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(),
>   AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See
>   https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

I read the documentation and can get it working by adding `.ToListAsync()` and evaluate it in `client/.net`, but then why cant this query be evaluated on `server/sql server`?

Comment: Recommendation: write the SQL that does what you want/need, rather than leaning on the query generator. It'll work on any runtime, and you'll have full control over the performance. Most ORM-style tools allow you to issue custom SQL

Comment: @MarcGravell And Dapper would be a great use for that here ;)

Comment: Are Amount & AccountNo computed? How are they defined?

Comment: You have to make sure every thing get recompiled when upgrading.  The compiler dependencies don't always recognize library upgrades.  Also make sure you update the mapping between the database and the c# classes.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman both are database columns

Comment: @juharr indeed, but I'll take baby steps en-route to Dapper :)